# How can I filter a List of complex objects so that if two have value for a field, I remove one based on criteria

Tags: java, list, lambda, filtering

I have a List of objects, some of which may be similar to others based on a certain field. In this case, I want to filter one based on the value of another field.

Here is an example of what I have coming in:

```
[
    {
        employeeId: 1230,
        firstName: "Ronald",
        lastName: "McDonald",
        device: "Laptop"
    },
    {
        employeeId: 2345,
        firstName: "Dennis",
        lastName: "Reynolds",
        device: "Laptop"
    },
    {
        employeeId: 1230,
        firstName: "Ronald",
        lastName: "McDonald",
        device: "Phone"
    }
]
```

I have 2 objects for Ronald McDonald (employee 1230). I want the Laptop for all employees unless they have a Phone, in which case I just want the phone. So I want to filter out the Ronald McDonald object with `device= "Laptop"` so that my output is as follows:

```
[
    {
        employeeId: 1230,
        firstName: "Ronald",
        lastName: "McDonald",
        device: "Phone"
    },
    {
        employeeId: 2345,
        firstName: "Dennis",
        lastName: "Reynolds",
        device: "Laptop"
    }
]
```

Filtering is easy enough, but for whatever reason I can't wrap my head around removing duplicates based on a condition.

Does any helpful soul have a solution to my situation?

I'm using Java 11, so I have access to Lambda functions, streams, all that good stuff.

**Edit:** My first crack at it is going terribly. I feel like I'm grouping ok, but I can't seem to filter within that group:

```
List<Employee> reducedEmpList = empList.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmployeeId,

     // Obviously this is not right:
     Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getDevice, (e1, e2) -> {
    // Clearly this is not how a comparator works
    if("Laptop".equalsIgnoreCase(e1.getDevice()){
        return e2;
      }
}))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through all the employees, and if the device is `Phone` search the list for the employee and add to the list `entriesToRemove` if another entry exists with that employee and the device is `Laptop`:

```
    List<Employee> entriesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
      for(Employee employee : list){
         if(employee.getDevice().equals("Phone")){
            entriesToRemove.addAll(list.stream().filter(e ->
            e.getEmployeeId() == employee.getEmployeeId() && e.getDevice().equals("Laptop"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
         }
    }
```

Finally remove the entries from the list with `removeAll`:

```
list.removeAll(entriesToRemove);
System.out.printf(list.toString());
```

**Edit**: Solution using Stream API:

```
List<Employee> reducedEmpList = list.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmployeeId,
   Collectors.collectingAndThen(toList(), listPerEmployee ->
   listPerEmployee.stream().filter(e -> e.getDevice().equals("Phone")).findFirst()
     .map(Collections::singletonList).orElse(listPerEmployee))))
     .values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(toList());
```

Output:

```
[Employee{employeeId=2345, device='Laptop'}, Employee{employeeId=1230, device='Phone'}]
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response! This is definitely a valid solution. However, more often than not the list of employees will be in the thousands, so I don't feel like using the for loop and filtering against the entire list for each iteration is an efficient solution.

Comment: Please, take a look at my updated answer with Stream API

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mergeFunction` of [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) to choose the one with "Phone" as the device when there's more than one:

```
Collection<Employee> filtered = employees.stream().collect(Collectors
    .toMap(e -> e.getEmployeeId(), e -> e,
    (a, b) -> "Phone".equals(a.getDevice())? a : b,
    LinkedHashMap::new)).values();
employees = new ArrayList<>(filtered);
```

I specified a `LinkedHashMap` as the intermediate storage so that any other employees (like Dennis) will remain in their relative positions, if that's important. If not, you can just use the 3 parameter overload of `toMap` and leave that off.

Note: this assumes that if there is more than one entry for a given employee, one of them always has a device of "Phone".